# How to create a single-dimensional, non-zero-based array in F#

Tags: arrays, f#

I tried to create a single-dimensional, non-zero-based array in F#. 
I need such arrays for interoperability with code written in another programming language.
Array2D.createBased function is intended to create a two-dimentional, non-zero-based array, but the F# language lacks Array.createBased function to create a single-dimentional, non-zero-based array. So, I tried to write my own function, but it does not work. Its code is here:

```
let createBased base1 length1 (initial : 'a) =           
       // the problem is here: System.Array ('a [*]) is not convertible to array ('a []), 
       // so InvalidCastException error is raised at run-time
       let A = Array.CreateInstance (typeof<'a>, [| length1 |], [| base1 |]) :?> 'a [] 

       for i in A.GetLowerBound(0) .. A.GetUpperBound(0) do A.[i] <- initial 
       A
```

Please help!

Comment: These arrays are a bit weird - They do have `getvalue` and `setvalue` methods that you could use manually though.

Comment: But I need single-dimensional, non-zero-based arrays in F# code for interop with foreign code. It's easy to create such an array in Visual Basic and Ada 2012. Why it is so difficult in F#?

Comment: That method will still create them - it hust looks like you can't convert to standard array types (this may be as non-zero based arrays are not CLS-compliant)

Comment: Yes, John. I cannot convert them to a standard array. I tried to circumvent that problem by using: Array2D.createBased 1 0 10 0 "", but that function produced a value of string [,] type instead of string [] that I want.

Comment: But you can just do `let A = Array.CreateInstance ...; A.SetValue(5,5)`

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is there any recipe enabling the A.[5] <- 5 syntax to be used instead of A.SetValue(5,5) syntax for System.Array in F#?

Comment: It seems that `'a[*]` and `'a[]` are just different types. Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx it says that non-zero based arrays aren't normally supported in .NET standard library. So it seems that they are just a special case, and probably have special internal representation that isn't compatible with conventional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

These arrays are not normally supported in .NET (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx - thanks for link e-i-s).

However, it is possible to provide a hackish solution that allow you to use the F# syntax.

Here is a very simple example

```
open System
type Hack() =
    let A = Array.CreateInstance (typeof<int>, [| 5 |], [| 5 |])
    member x.Item with get(y:int) = A.GetValue(y) and set (v:int) (y:int) = A.SetValue(y,v)

let a = new Hack()
printfn "%A" (a.[8])
a.[8]<-1
printfn "%A" (a.[8])
```

Comment: I think this is an OK solution as long as you don't need to use this kind of array where you would use regular arrays -- it's still a different type from `'a[]`. So you can't use `Array.map`, or any other array function that takes `'a[]` as an argument. In a sense, this isn't even an array you're creating :)